# Unserializing Laravel Objects after Caching

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Trying to cache objects for later use. But I when I retrieve the object - it's no longer an object, it's Json.

I have tried unserializing, but that creates more errors.

How does one retrieve data and convert it back to an object with objects inside?

```
$listing = Cache::remember("listing_details.$listing->id", 25, function() use ($listing,$user) {

                    $listing->getListingDetails($listing);
                    $owner = User::find($listing->user_id);
                    $listing->owner = $owner;
                    return $listing;
                });
```

Comment: What does `getListingDetails` return? Because Laravel caches the result you return from the `Cache::remember` closure without doing any data type manipulation. So if you return a collection of objects then it will cache a collection of objects.

Comment: It returns an object of the type ListingDetails. The problem that it's returning Json from cache, that can't be dejson-ed back into objects.

Comment: Are you by any chance doing `echo $listing;` or `return $listing;` to output the value of `$listing`? Because if you are, then you should be aware that Laravel automatically detects and converts collections and objects to JSON when sending the response (because it's a pretty nice feature for APIs). You should instead try doing `dump($listing);` and that should output the original data type contained in the variable.

Comment: I've been using return. I'll try dump or dd tomorrow

Comment: In the end, i don't have access to the codebase. But it was JSON that was stored in the Cache.